# How to add new select box every time I change value of new created selectbox in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new number input and a checkbox when I select a value from selectbox.After I add a selectbox that selectbox should add a new selctbox.
I dont know what is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance.

```js
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#arithmetic' + counter).change(function(e)
                                    {
    counter++
    if( $('#arithmetic' + counter ).val() == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/'  || '%' )
    {

      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' +counter);
      newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="number" name="input' + counter + ' "  id="input' + counter + '" value="" > \

<select id="arithmetic' + counter + '" >\

<option id="select" value="Select" selected>Select</option>\

<option id="add" value="+">+</option><option id="subtract" value="-">-</option>\

<option id="multiply" value="*">*</option><option id="division" value="/"></option>\
<option id="percentage" value="   %">%</option></select>');


      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#container center");
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <center>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <input type="number"/>
      <select id="arithmetic1">
        <option id="select" value="Select" selected>Select</option>
        <option id="add" value="+">+</option>
        <option id="subtract" value="-">-</option>
        <option id="multiply" value="*">*</option>
        <option id="division" value="/">/</option>
        <option id="percentage" value="%">%</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </center>

</div>
```

Comment: Cant understand what you want, confused between `checkbox`, `selectbox` and `input`. Be clear what you want?

Comment: Not to mention constructs like `$(document.createElement('div'))` are silly. Use `$('<div/>')` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [delegate the events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on the newly created elements. So, what you need to do is, instead of:

```
$('#arithmetic' + counter).change(function(e)
```

Change it to:

```
$("#container").on("change", '#arithmetic' + counter, function(e)
```

And there are a few mistakes...

1. Replace:

   ```
   $(document.createElement('div'))
   ```

   With:

   ```
   $("<div />")
   ```
2. Remove the `<center>` tag.

Comment: after change in code still I am not able to add new div with newly created div,
it adds when I click on TextBoxDiv1 but not on TextBoxDiv2.

Comment: @parthmahida Can you please clarify again?